# How to fix scope issues when using an onclick event in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, onclick

I am curretly experiencing difficulties implementing an onclick event within a for loop. Instead of alerting the respective value it always returns undefined (presumably a scope problem, because the iteration itself works fine)

Until now I tried to pass on the i variable to the onclick function; however, with little success

```
for (var i = 0; i < timeSpanLength; i++) {
            // creating the wrap for the month
            var month = document.createElement("div");
            month.className = 'month_element';

            var reference_month = document.createElement("span");
            reference_month.innerHTML = time_span[i];

            //onclick event
            reference_month.onclick = function(i) {
                var month_beginning = signup_date;
                var month_end = time_span[i];
                alert(month_end);
                //searchForData(month_beginning, month_end);
            };

            //append to container
            month.appendChild(reference_month);
            document.getElementById('time_container').appendChild(month);
        }
```

The expected outcome is to trigger an alert which displays the same month which is displayed in the span element above. I need the variable to pass it on to another function.

Any help is highly appreciated since I am beginner in javascript.

Comment: Instead of `var i = 0;` use `let i = 0;`

Comment: `reference_month.onclick = function(i)` <-- that `i` is `event`

Comment: @Clarity thanks a lot! In addition I had to remove the i from the onclick function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < timeSpanLength; i++) {
 (function (index) {
   // creating the wrap for the month
            var month = document.createElement("div");
            month.className = 'month_element';

            var reference_month = document.createElement("span");
            reference_month.innerHTML = time_span[index];

            //onclick event
            reference_month.onclick = function() {
                var month_beginning = signup_date;
                var month_end = time_span[index];
                alert(month_end);
                //searchForData(month_beginning, month_end);
            };

            //append to container
            month.appendChild(reference_month);
            document.getElementById('time_container').appendChild(month);
 })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This callback function handler is forming a closure with  respect to the outer scope. Also `var` has a function scope, so in essence the block of code can be re-written as:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < timeSpanLength; i++) {
  ...
  //onclick event
  reference_month.onclick = function(i) {
            var month_beginning = signup_date;
            var month_end = time_span[i];
            alert(month_end);
            //searchForData(month_beginning, month_end);
   };
   ...
}
```

So the `var i` is hoisted to the top and when the loop completes the value of `i` is `timeSpanLength.length` and this is what you use to access `time_span[i]` and that returns `undefined`.

Since with `var` the binding remains the same, the handlers registered will be referring the last value of `i` in the loop.

So you either need to use `let` in the for-loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < timeSpanLength; i++) { ... }
```

Or an IIFE which forms a new scope bound to each new value of `i` from the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < timeSpanLength; i++) { 
   (function(i){
      reference_month.onclick = function(i) {
            var month_beginning = signup_date;
            var month_end = time_span[i];
            alert(month_end);
            //searchForData(month_beginning, month_end);
       };
    })(i) 
}
```